# Test Pdf Files with C# selenium web driver using iTextSharp library

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Now, I need to test a pdf file downloaded from a web site to. I've searched and found that code but I don't understand how to open the pdf by using the name only?
How can I open it from the downloads folder.

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
using System.Text;

namespace PDFExtractor
{
    public class PDFExtractor
    {
        public static string ExtractTextFromPDF(string pdfFileName)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            // Create a reader for the given PDF file
            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFileName))
            {
                // Read pages
                for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
                {
                    SimpleTextExtractionStrategy strategy =
                        new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                    string pageText =
                        PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, strategy);
                    result.Append(pageText);
                }
            }
            return result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any help, please

Answer (score 0):

you just have to enter the path to this pdf.
Like @"C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\PDF.pdf

Comment: Thanks @Czarek B for help, now I've finished this and will try your way.